# django bulk excel file read is too slow using xlrd

Tags: python, django, excel, xlrd

I am loading excel file in django model and reading it using xlrd and storing in database.
It takes 1 minute to load around 20k rows ..but my file has 160k rows it took aroud 8 minutes ,so I need to reduce the time to read and store to be less than a min for this kind of bulk file. What should I do to reduce load time. what are all the possible ways ??

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Upload(file = request.FILES['file'])
            newdoc.save()
            xlbook = open_workbook(newdoc.file.name)
            sheet = xlbook.sheet_by_index(0)
            field = [sheet.cell_value(0,c) for c in range(sheet.ncols)]
            temp = [sheet.cell_value(c,0) for c in range(sheet.nrows)]
            value = [[sheet.cell_value(r,c) for c in range(sheet.ncols)]for r in range (sheet.nrows)]
            data = {}
            if request.POST.get('check'):       
                Sales.objects.filter(OrderID__in = temp[1:]).delete()
            for n in range(0,sheet.nrows):
                if n > 0:
                    list = value[n]
                    for i in range(0,len(field)):
                        data[field[i]] = list[i]
                if data:
                    date_value = xldate_as_tuple(sheet.cell_value(n,1),xlbook.datemode)
                    data["Date"] = datetime(*date_value[:3])
                    add = Sales.objects.get_or_create(**data)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/salesdata/')
    if request.method == 'GET':
       form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES) 
    return render(request,'salesdata/upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Your question is more about efficient reading with `xlrd` and less about `Django`.

Comment: of course , yes ! but is there any package which works faster reading excel and write for django model.

Answer (score 2):

One, *don't do this in a view*. Start a background task with Celery or so, then return. Don't keep the user waiting.

Second, the problem is that you're doing a `get_or_create` for every row; that is slow. You can make a list of unsaved `Sales` instance first, then create them with `Sales.objects.bulk_create`. That way it's one insert query, which will be lots faster.

Unfortunately, that only does inserts, it doesn't update data that is already there. Fixing that is more than I want to put in this answer right now, and the best way depends on how many of the rows will be updates compared to inserts in the usual case. Worst case, you really do have to have an sql UPDATE for each row, and that will always be slow.

Comment: is there any other package to read excel faster in a different way ?? I need some kind batch upload and read of excel file, should be with some lesser complexity.

Comment: I don't think you can do better than xlrd, I've always found it to be quite good. But as I said, I don't think the Excel reading is your speed problem, the database writing is.

Comment: can you suggest the method of writing data into django model or database..?? I am asking for some different code to do that.